# Crashing on tableView reloadData includes crash report

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash-reports, crashlytics, crash-log

Im using Crashlytics for crash management. I recently got this crash and I am trying to understand why this crash may have occurred.

[image]

Here is my `UITableView+ReloadTransition.m`:

```
#import "UITableView+ReloadTransition.h"

 @implementation UITableView (ReloadTransition)
- (void)reloadDataWithFade:(BOOL)animated {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.alpha=0.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self reloadData];//line 17
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        self.alpha=1.0;
        }];
    }];
}
```

Any help is greatly advised? Im kind of a newbie when it comes to crash reports.

**Update** to include more information.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reloadData without animation? Can you show the rest of the Threads on the crash report?

Comment: It looks like the problem occurred while doing `reloadData` following an animation, and very likely you had just done an add/remove operation with animation and you somehow got the number of sections mucked up.

Comment: @HotLicks hmmm, interesting. There are no remove operations taking place anyway.

Comment: @Spectravideo328 please see the above

Comment: What about add operations??

Comment: @HotLicks i dont add objects on a row to row basis, what I do is reload the tables content on the UIRefreshControls action, ie, pulling down.

Comment: Are your UITableVIewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate always "in sync" internally and with each other?  Ie, if you update the number of rows, might that happen asynchronously and "catch" a screen transition such that the numberOfRowsInSection result is inconsistent with the actual data source row tables?

Comment: @HotLicks this is an interesting suggestion. Could you elaborate on `catch a screen transitions`, what do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean that, say, you're receiving a network message in background and updating the data source and, say, the user presses the Back button in the app to bring back your table.

Comment: @HotLicks this may be happening. Ill look into this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try swizzling methods. This way i am fading table view on reloading, hope this help you.

```
@implementation UITableView (Animation)

+(void)load
{
Method original, swizzle;

original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(reloadData));
swizzle = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swizzled_reloadData));
method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzle);
}

-(void)swizzled_reloadData
{
[self swizzled_reloadData];

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.type = kCATransitionFromBottom;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
transition.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;
transition.duration = 0.55;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFade;
[[self layer] addAnimation:transition forKey:@"UITableViewReloadDataAnimationKey"];

}

@end
```